# Changing of date format in apex

Tags: apex, datetime, date, format

1.How to change the  2021-06-15T02:30:00.000Z to date(15/06/2021) in Apex? I have tried  multiple ways but not working please help me with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can convert this using `Date` static class.

```
System.debug(Date.valueOf('2021-06-15T02:30:00.000Z'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I may assume, that you need DateTime, not Date, because you have hours and minutes specified.

`Datetime.valueOf()` works for format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, so you need to replace `T` with space and remove `Z`.

```
String toConvert = '2021-06-15T02:30:00.000Z';
toConvert = toConvert.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z', '');
Datetime actualDatetime = Datetime.valueOf(dateTimeFromData);
```

If you only need Date value, then @Nagendra Singh answer is even easier to implement.